# How to access checkout values in Shopify checkout.liquid?

Tags: javascript, shopify, checkout, shopify-template

I have access to Shopify Plus. I need to push the checkout object details into a variable. This is my current code on [shopify checkout.liquid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z8nF.png)

```
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
var items = {{checkout.line_items}}
window.dataLayer.push({
 'items': items
 });
 
</script>
```

What can I do to ensure I have the checkout details available for access on each step. I need the items on the checkout and post checkout i need the transaction data. please let me know what can be done. Thanks

Comment: NB: Any time you move variables from Liquid to Javascript, you should make use of the `| json` filter to ensure that any values/output is in a javascript-legal format. (Example: `{{ checkout.line_items | json }}`  Be aware that not every object is 'public' in a way that can is compatible with this filter, so if that alone doesn't solve your issue you may need to introduce a loop in the form of `{% for item in checkout.line_items %} /* Javascript output */ {% endfor %}`

Comment: Thanks @DaveB for your suggestion will try it out and post